# How to take latest changes from dev branch to my current branch

Tags: git

We have below branches on which we work.

```
master
dev
person A
person B
```

We both keep working on our branches i.e. `person A` or `person B` (working on same project). When `person A` finish the work, he commits changes to his branche and then create a pull request to merge the changes into `dev`, which other person `B` views and approve. After approval, the changes are then saved in `dev`.

How `B` can take the latest changes which `A` has done, from `dev` to his branch `person B`. We are using [github desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) to do all the git push/pull but happy to learn commands too. Thanks.

Comment: `git pull origin dev` is the usual method, assuming `A` has pushed his changes to the upstream.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's a good practice for the person *B* to get new changes into their branch `b`
as soon as feasible after person *A* pushes the changes to `dev`/`main`.

This is so that person *B* works on latest code and their eventual merge to `dev`/`main` is easy.

#### Option 1, pull

1. Commit all changes to branch `feature_branch` (git status shows `clean`)
2. `git checkout dev`
3. `git pull` - this fetches (downloads) the changes onto `B`'s computer  (into a branch `origin/dev`) **and** merges these changes into the currently checked out local branch (in this case branch `dev`). This operation should normally be a 'fast-forward' (so no merge conflicts)
4. `git checkout feature_branch`
5. `git merge dev` - this merges changes from `b`'s local `dev` to the `feature_branch`.
6. `git mergetool` - resolve conflicts
7. `git commit` - commit your merge

With this option `b`'s both local `dev` and `feature_branch` have latest changes.

#### Option 2, fetch

1. Commit all changes to branch `feature_branch` (git status shows `clean`)
2. `git fetch origin dev` - this downloads latest changes to `dev`, but *doesn't* merge them to local `dev`
3. `git merge origin/dev` - this merges changes from the downloaded version of `dev` to the `feature_branch`.

In this scenario `b`'s local `feature_branch` will have the most recent changes from `dev` *as they are on the remote repo* and their local `dev` will not have these changes. This is OK, since `b` isn't working on `dev`, (s)he's working on `feature_branch`.

---

I like option 2 as I don't need to checkout `dev`, but both options are equally correct.

Comment: Option 2 causes my `dev` branch to be merged into my `feature_branch` without any commited changes in the merge commit. I only noticed because I had several merge conflicts using Option 1 but not using Option 2. What am I doing wrong @tymtam? Thanks very much :)

Comment: Do you have local commits in dev that weren't pushed?

Comment: No everything is up to date and pushed. I used Option 1 and it worked. I just though I found a gotcha that might help others

Answer (score 7):

These are the steps that I do for that, though using command line interface.

1. Checkout dev branch (git checkout dev)
2. Get the latest of dev branch (git pull)
3. Checkout branch B (git checkout B)
4. Merge dev branch to branch B (git merge dev)

You can follow these steps using your github desktop.

Comment: 0. Make sure all changes in B are committed.